# How to reply an user having name in non-English character?

Tags: support

I just wanted to mention [this user](https://superuser.com/users/86129/) in my comment, but unable to figure out, how? I thought, only English is allowed on SE.

I am on smartphone at this time in which copy-paste isn't easy on websites.

Is there another way to mention him by numbers etc.?

Comment: While only English is allowed, English is a language that is written with latin characters. SE allows all Unicode characters except the ♦ in usernames.

Answer (score 4):

Copy and paste user's nick, like this: `Ярослав Рахматуллин`

That's the only way that works for me.

Comment: Actually, to create a notification in the user's inbox, you only have to copy the first three characters :)

Comment: @slh, as long as the user has already posted once on the current thread right?

Comment: @terdon Well, if they aren't participating (or are not the post owner or an editor of the post), then they wouldn't get a notification anyway – even if you used the full name.