# How to include in a comment a call to a user with unicode characters?

Tags: support, bug

I try to add in a comment `@Pekka웃`.
It pops up an error.

> Comments cannot contain that content.
>
> Unlucky.

I remove the last character `웃` and the comment was accepted without any problem...
He answers to my comment so I suppose it was notified, but the *pop up* didn't suggest me anything.

**Should we say that *"this is a  bug"* ?**

Beyond this workaround (admitted that it works in all the cases), it exist any other way to do it, maybe via *user number* ?

---

I read this question about non latin characters in the nickname, *"[How to reply an user having name in non-English character?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5981/how-to-reply-an-user-having-name-in-non-english-character)"*,  but the solution proposed there (copy and paste the whole nickname) didn't allow  at all to post the comment.

In the comment of that answer made by *slhck* is written *Actually, to create a notification in the user's inbox, you only have to copy the first three characters* Dec 8 '12 at 11:34.

So on one side I suppose it was at least notified, but on the other side I'm asking myself ***In general if there are 2 or more users with the same initial part of the nickname, to whom the comment will be notified***?

Comment: Comment notifications go only to people who have participated in a specific post (question or answer), which includes the author, any editors, & previous commenters (whose comments are still there).  In most cases, the system will identify candidates it recognizes, and if the first few letters aren't unique, you can select the applicable one.  I've never run into a case where the entire enterable names were identical for multiple users, which would mean that two users with the same name both participated on that post, so I don't know what would happen.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks for the answer. For what I remember I received notification when I have a comment on my own answer, or if I commented and someone after write at_Hastur. They explicitly said that are enough 3 letters. So if I change my nick in `fixer0123` and someone here below write `@fix`, I don't know who of us will receive the notification... BTW If  I change my nickname in `fixer웃` no one can address a comment specifically to me... I think this is a bug.

Comment: I ran into the same comment addressing problem with Ciro Santilli 六四事件 法轮功 包卓轩.  :-)  It's a minimum of three characters, but you need enough characters to uniquely address a participant on the post.  It doesn't happen often that two participants can't be distinguished with the characters you can enter plus the system doesn't present a choice of candidates.  "fixer0123" would work (unique).  "fix" or "fixer" would typically display all candidates on the post (fixer웃, fixer1234, fixer0123 if all were participants), and you could select.

Comment: Perfect I got it. That's the point: I cannot send the comment only to fixer웃, because when I select it and I try to send,  the page  **always pop up  the error message** above ("Comments cannot contain that content. unlucky "). It smells like a bug.